# Python/Spyder - friendly name of class Type when importing from custom package

Tags: python, spyder, python-packaging

I am building a python package and would like to understand how to give a user friendly name for the class type that will be displayed in a variable explorer when using an IDE such as Spyder.

When I import from pandas and generate a DataFrame object the "Type" displayed in the variable explorer is "DataFrame"

[image]

however, if I look at the underlying type it shows the full path to the class...

[image]

[image]

When I do this for my own class, the Type is displayed as the full path, rather than just the name of the class itself...

[image]

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It's not possible at the moment (May 2021) to define how to display the type of objects in our Variable Explorer, sorry.